# Paypal sandbox zero balance testing failed

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created a buyer account on sandbox with zero amount and purchased items with that amount but still it set `payment_status` variable to `Completed`. What could be the cause, should I go for additional zero testing configuration with sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the buyer account you created must have a credit card associated with it so that when there aren't PayPal funds available it would use the credit card.  In the sandbox, of course, this is all for testing.

Log into the account, go into the profile, and see if there is a credit card added.  If so, delete it and that should allow you to run tests like you're wanting.

Alternatively, you could use [negative testing in the sandbox](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/) to test specific error codes.